# Can anyone explain this BigQuery SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT
 warehouse.warehouse_id,
 CONCAT(warehouse.state,': ', warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
 COUNT(orders.order_id) AS num_of_orders,
  (SELECT
   COUNT(*)
   FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders`) AS total_orders,
  CASE
   WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) <= 0.20
   THEN 'fulfilled 0-20% fo the orders'
   WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) > 0.20
   AND COUNT(orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) <= 0.60
   THEN 'fulfilled 21-60% of the orders'
 ELSE 'fulfilled more than 6-% of the orders'
 END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM
 `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.warehouse` AS warehouse
LEFT JOIN
 `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders ON
 orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
 warehouse_id,
 warehouse_name
HAVING
 COUNT(orders.order_id) >0
```

I tried getting to get along with it, but couldn't, specially the subquery and after it!
Will highly appreciate it. What I want is, what is the query trying to do and what exactly should I expect as the result from this query.

Answer (score -1):

For all warehouses that have had fulfilled at least 1 order `HAVING COUNT(orders.order_id) >0`

Calculate, for each warehouse, the following:

1. The number of orders fulfilled by the warehouse

```
COUNT(orders.order_id) AS num_of_orders,
```

2. The total number of orders fulfilled by all warehouses

```
(SELECT
   COUNT(*)
   FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders`) AS total_orders
```

3. A summary of the warehouse's fulfillment rate, based on the following criteria:

   - If the warehouse has fulfilled 0-20% of the orders, the summary should be "fulfilled 0-20% of the orders"

   ```
   WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) <= 0.20
   THEN 'fulfilled 0-20% fo the orders'
   ```

   - If the warehouse has fulfilled 21-60% of the orders, the summary should be "fulfilled 21-60% of the orders"

   ```
   WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) > 0.20
   AND COUNT(orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `master-deck-385111.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) <= 0.60
   ```

   - If the warehouse has fulfilled more than 60% of the orders, the summary should be "fulfilled more than 60% of the orders"

   ```
   ELSE 'fulfilled more than 6-% of the orders'
   ```

Also, that last bit seems to contain a typo and should probably be changed to `60%`

Comment: Thank you! But can you tell me what and how the subquery relates to the outer query? WHY the subquery?

Comment: The subquery has no relation to the outside query. It runs on its own and produces a scalar result. In this case it gets a count of every order in `warehouse_orders` and spits back the response. That response is aliased `num_of_orders` when it's first used, and then subsequent uses, inside the case expression, it is the denominator to determine warehouse fulfillment rate, where the numerator is that particular warehouses count of orders.

Comment: That being said, it's a little heavy handed to repeat it over and over again. I'm not familiar with BigQuery's sophistication when it comes to optimization, but hopefully it recognizes the re-use of the same subquery and only fetches that scalar response once. If that isn't the case, then there's probably better ways to write this sql.